# Is there a way to restore deleted Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I recently had my computer serviced by Geek Squad (never again) and they deleted my firefox.exe and all my bookmarks. When I browsed to C:\%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox there was nothing there except a thumbnail of my old desktop background. I tried using the file recovery tool Recuva on the C:\%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox directory but it came back with no files. I ended up reinstalling Firefox. Is there any way I can get my old bookmarks back?

Comment: If you used the Sync feature, you have a good chance :) .

Comment: You can try using a recovery tool like [Recuva] (http://www.filehippo.com/download_recuva) and try searching for bookmarks*.json. If you find such files, try restoring it and import in into Firefox

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I've recovered what looks to be a .json file with my old bookmarks. How do I go about importing this to Firefox now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a .json file you can open the bookmarks window and go to import and backup, restore, and choose your file. Note that this will overwrite anything new you've added. Remember to setup sync or otherwise backup your profile in case this happens again.